Sometimes Dialog Box content is not display
async function openDialog(event) {
        let url = 'localhost:4200/#/openDialog';
    
        await Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync(gettoken);
     
        function gettoken(res) {
            try {
               token = res.value; 
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync( 
                      `${url}/${token}`,
                      { width: 40, height: 53, displayInIframe: true },
                      function (result) {}
                      
            }
        }
    }

Dialog Box content is display every time.

First, call API in try and than store value of response in res, than try below code.
async function openDialog(event) {
    let url = 'localhost:4200/#/openDialog';
    let token;

    try {
        const res = await Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync();
        token = res.value;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error getting access token:', err);
        return;
    }

    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
        `${url}/${token}`,
        { width: 40, height: 53, displayInIframe: true },
        function (result) {
            
        }
    );
}


it is not work.


Content is not show inside dialog box sometime.

This occurred because your dialog is opening before your data is assigned to your object. First, ensure your data is set correctly to your object before opening the dialog. I've faced a similar issue and used setTimeout to delay the dialog opening.
  Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(window.location.origin + "/Dialogs/mydata.html", { height: 54, width: 44, displayInIframe: true },
        function (asyncResult) {
            rDialog = asyncResult.value;
            var Data = {
                Id: Id,
                Name: Name,
            }
            rDialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, rDialogRecieved);
            //rDialogRecieved recived event which is trigger from this dialog.
            setTimeout(function () { rDialog.messageChild(JSON.stringify(Data)); }, 3000);
            //Use this setTimeout to send your data it'll help I'm Also Facing this same issue it's fixed using this; 
        }
    );

